# How do I host a static website inside a Wordpress multisite installation?

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I would like to do the following:

```
Wordpress Multisite
- hosted static site in the directory but not utilising wordpress
  Wordpress additional site
  - /blog subfolder
  Wordpress additional site
  - /jobboard subfolder
  Wordpress additional site
  - /other subfolder
```

In short, I want to host my static website as the main Wordpress Multisite's site. It's an exported HTML Website ready to go. I haven't got time to convert it into a Wordpress site.

Is this possible, and if so, how do I go about doing it?

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to just drop the static website into any WordPress directory.

This is made possible, because of the rewrite rules in the `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Before rewriting any request, the rewrite engine will check to see whether the request maps to an existent file or directory. If it doesn't, it passes the request to WordPress.